# Variance of IV estimator

Tags: variance, econometrics, asymptotics, instrumental-variables

Could someone please demonstrate how to get the asymptotic variance of the IV estimator in a simple regression (as in Wooldridge):

[image]

The variance of Beta 1 is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the notation in the paste-ons? What are $z_i$, $x_i$ and $y_i$ representing in the regression? Which variables are the predictor variables and which one is the dependent variable?

Comment: Sorry, thanks! X is the instrumental variable for endogenous explanatory variable x and y is the dependent variable.